# The property "VisualTree" can only be set once

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I got a problem which I do not understand. My Visual Studio gives me following 2 errors:

> The property "VisualTree" can only be set once.
>
> The property 'VisualTree' is set more than once.

This is my XAML:

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="SettingsListItemControl">
    <TextBlock Text="Settings" FontSize="24" />
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="640" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="SettingItemTemplate" x:DataType="vm:SettingItemViewModel">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}"/>
            <ToggleSwitch IsOn="{x:Bind IsActive}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I do not know why I can not bind IsActive, it gives me an error here...
Seems like he also has a problem with DataTemplate.
My question seems pretty basic, I am a beginner when it comes to XAML and DataBinding :)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 8):

In your ItemTemplate, you need a parent panel for that TextBlock/ToggleSwitch that can hold children, wrap them in a StackPanel or Grid or something. Error gone. :)

So swap it for something like this;

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:Name="SettingItemTemplate" x:DataType="vm:SettingItemViewModel">
      <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}"/>
         <ToggleSwitch IsOn="{x:Bind IsActive}"/>
      </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: preferably grid over stackpanel because grid will fill the whole space and StackPanel will take space of the underlying items.